# How do I enter a list of text from a txt file to a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
activation = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/aside/div/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/span')
code = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/aside/div/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/div/input')

list = open("C:\Users\infin\Desktop\List.txt", "r")
```

I want to enter a list of code from List.txt into `code` as long as `activation` is true and create a loop depending on how many elements the list has

For example, if the list has 5 codes, I want to see that if `activation` is true or not. If it is true, it will timeout for 120 seconds (I can do this part)
Then after 120 seconds, it will enter the codes from the `list.txt` to `code`

I am still learning python and I'm trying out different stuffs and learning new words in python

Comment: This should be covered by any decent tutorial; most of which are free so there's no reason not to go through one or two. Go back to the basics. SO is not intended to replace those.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I searched them but didn't find what I want. I may not be using the correct terms. What is this called?

Comment: it's unclear whether you want assign value to code variable, or paste the file content to the input box. if latter, use `element.send_keys(text)`

Comment: if you have codes in separated lines `codes = open(...).read().split('\n')`. And later you have to use `for`-loop to `send_key` with single code to `input` and get again `activation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem but if you have codes in separated lines then you can do

```
 all_codes = open("C:\\Users\\infin\\Desktop\\List.txt", "r").read().split('\n')
```

Better use \\ in path because \ is used for special chars like `\n` (new line), `\t` (tab), etc. - even in path - and single \ can make problem. OR use prefix `r` for `raw string`.

```
 all_codes = open(r"C:\Users\infin\Desktop\List.txt", "r").read().split('\n')
```

And next you need `for`-loop to get single code, send it to input and check result.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

for value in all_codes:
    code = driver.find_element_xpath('//*[@id="__layout"]//section[1]/div[1]//form/div/input')

    code.send_key(value)
    code.send_key(Keys.ENTER)

    activation = driver.find_element_xpath('//*[@id="__layout"]//section[1]//form/div[2]/div/span')

    if activation.text == '... some text ...':
        break # exit loop before end of codes
```

You may need to use again `find_element` in every loop because `find_element` gives reference to object in memory and when you put `code` then it may change HTML and element can be moved in different place in memory.

You could also try to find shorter `xpath` with `//` or with `classes` or `ids`

Comment: yeah thanks for the help, it worked!  I was mainly facing problems because of the `\n`.

Comment: @TasrifRahman So why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: @Prophet sorry I am new to this community so I forgot about it. I 'answered' it